# Importing Electron classes with Typescript

Tags: typescript, electron

How can I import Electron classes into a Typescript file, so that the intellisense is functioning?

For example, I'd like to turn this:

```
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');
var app = require('app');
app.on("ready", function() {
  var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 600,
    height: 800
  });
});
```

into something like this (doesn't work):

```
/// <reference path="./typings/github-electron/github-electron.d.ts"/>
var app = GitHubElectron.App;
app.on("ready", function() {
  var mainWindow = new GitHubElectron.BrowserWindow({
    width: 600,
    height: 800
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use type annotations on the return values of the `require` function calls:

```
var BrowserWindow: GithubElectron.BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');
var app = GitHubElectron.App = require('app');
app.on("ready", function() {
  var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 600,
    height: 800
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Two questions, though I'm not sure if they're related:  (1) When running the application it throws an uncaught exception that GitHubElectron is not defined. In the github-electron d.ts that's the module it's defined in. Maybe I'm misunderstanding how to reference the class though, I'm new to TS and Electron. (2) I'm getting an error creating a new instance of the browser-window. "Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature."  When I define the options as GitHubElectron.BrowserWindowOptions it seems to compile OK. I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Definitions generally ship with tests. In this case : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/github-electron/github-electron-main-tests.ts is your guidance on how to use the definitions

Comment: Perfect, that's going to save me a lot of guessing going forward.

Comment: @inyourcorner Can you pls share the code by which you were able pass the BrowserWIndowsOptions to the BrowserWindow constructor? I am not able to make it work.

Comment: @rmchndrng From basarat's link they are using import instead of var to bring in the BrowserWindow class. I had the same problem and doing this made the issue go away.

Comment: If i remember correctly I used those tests as my guidelines for using the objects. Basically what @Mike Cheel is suggesting.