# Can't connect to my WebSocket from within my Angular2 app

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, angular

Hej there.

I have a app using Node.js/Electron/Angular2 (TypeScript). Using socket.io I created a WebSocket. Everything works fine, as long as I'm not inside my Angular2 app.

I tried the whole day to get this running, without luck. I downloaded a working tutorial, but can't find the missing link. Drives me crazy!

- This is my [electron.js](http://pastie.org/10762595) starting the app, creating the websocket server side
- This is my [index.html](http://pastie.org/10762597) with working websocket, but as native JavaScript code
- This is my [root component](http://pastie.org/10762599) of Angular2 trying to get the websocket running

The error - wich does not stop the compilation - I get, is `root.component.ts(14,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'io'.`.

How can I get rid of that error? Or better: What's the best practice for this websocket communication inside Angular2?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I solved this issue this way:

1. Installed socket.io-client typings `$ tsd install socket.io-client` and
2. added a typings reference to my main.ts file `///<reference path="../../typings/socket.io-client/socket.io-client.d.ts"/>`.
3. Installed socket.io-client Node.js module `$ npm install --save socket.io-client` and
4. added this module to my index.html `<script src="../node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>`

Now I can simply work with the socket inside any Angular2 component, without adding any extra lines.

```
socket = null;

constructor() {
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:8181');
    this.socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

And for reference, this is my server socket code inside my main Electron .js file:

```
var server = require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {})
    socket = require('socket.io')(server, {});

server.listen(8181);

socket.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('news', {hello: 'world'});
    socket.on('my other event', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps anyone later. Thank to Thierry Templier and dvlsg for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would note that if you're using electron that you shouldn't *really* consider electron.js to be server side. It's more of a client launcher / bootstrap, and must be running on each client. You'd have to have a separate node application (and I would strongly suggest it, in the case of `socket.io`) to truly make your code server side.

As for your question, you could try adding `import io from 'socket.io-client'` or `var io = require('socket.io-client')` in your root component (after you `npm install socket.io-client`, if necessary).

Comment: Thanks dvlsg. This is a desktop app only and I need Angular2 to communicate with Electron and I was told, that a web socket makes sense here, to keep client/server separated.

Comment: Ah. Apologies, I missed that you were using Typescript. I will delete this answer, since it's not relevant information to your problem.

Comment: Actually, holding off on that -- I believe my and Thierry's suggestion of using `import` would also work without needing to add a `<script>` tag to your index.html, and is probably the preferred way of including the module (for at least avoiding adding to the global scope). You may also want to look into electron's built in [IPC style messaging](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-main.md) since Electron has a native solution for renderer / main communication.

Comment: IPC is a good hint. But I'm still struggling with the logic of getting a module work in my TypeScrip Angular2 app. Right now I'm just trying to execute this `ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping');` inside my `root.component` constructor, without luck. What's the best way to use the mentioned `import` functionality to do it?

Comment: Good question. `const ipcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;` would translate into `import { ipcMain } from 'electron'`, I believe. That may or may not be what you need though, which would depend on which version of `electron` you have. You probably also need to look into tsd typings for the electron classes as well -- [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31302253/importing-electron-classes-with-typescript) may be helpful to you.

Comment: These tests including [ipcMain](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/github-electron/github-electron-main-tests.ts) and [ipcRenderer](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/github-electron/github-electron-renderer-tests.ts) may help point you in the right direction, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the socket.io typings (see this link: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/socket.io/socket.io.d.ts) using the command:

```
$ tsd install socket.io
```

Then you need import it:

```
import * as io from 'socket.io';
```

Comment: Thanks Thierry. The `$ tsd install socket.io` worked. But shouldn't I use [socket.io-client](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/socket.io-client/socket.io-client.d.ts)? Although, both ways don't work.

My [root.component](http://pastie.org/10763607) doesn't throw any TypeScript errors anymore while compiling, but the Electron console says `GET file:///Users/hoferma/Projects/sharktank-desktop/source/socket.io-client net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think that you fixed the compilation part... Where does this error occur at runtime?

Comment: It appeard when trying to talk to the socket. I fixed this issue meanwhile. Anyway, thanks for the awesome help.